# Laravel's Blade: New line appends space to former echo

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, echo, indentation, laravel-blade

I have 2 fields - country and city - which I want to display like this: **Country, City** (with one space after the comma). The only way I can do that now is to put everything in one line:

```
<li>{{{ $obj->country }}}@if($obj->city){{{ ', '.$obj->city }}}@endif</li>
```

This is truly ridiculous.

Now, let's say I want to make it readable:

```
<li>
    {{{ $obj->country }}}
    @if($edu->city)
        {{{ ', '.$obj->city }}}
    @endif
</li>
```

As soon as the second echo goes to a new line, the whole string is displayed with additional space after "Country": **Country , City**.

Super annoying. Anyone knows how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do this

```
<li>
    @if($edu->city)
        {{{ $obj->country.', '.$obj->city }}}  
    @else
        {{{ $obj->country }}}
    @endif
</li>
```

Looks very readable to me :)

Answer (score 1):

There's another way: use an accessor in your model. For brevity, I'm using PHP's ternary operator - you could go a little more verbose and have an if/else.

```
public function getCountryAndCityAttribute() {
  return $this->country . ($this->city ? $this->city : '');
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
<li>{{{ $obj->country_and_city }}}</li>
```